# The translation of a user-shell-folder is lost

Tags: windows-10, language, user-profiles

In a Dutch installation of Windows-10 I had originally correct Dutch names for the user-shell folders like '*Documents*' and '*Pictures*', ie. in Dutch '*Documenten*' and '*Afbeeldingen*'.

Unfortunately I deleted or moved a folder in a certain situation that I do not remember. And now the '*Pictures*' user-shell-folder is not displayed in Dutch anymore but just in English. The other ones are still displayed in Dutch.

I looked in the registry, in a hidden folder for libraries, I tried a hidden '*desktop.ini*' file, I can't solve it. My aim is to restore the translation of '*Pictures*' into Dutch ('*Afbeeldingen*').

EDIT:

I solved this by deleting and recreating my user profile.
However after some time the exact same situation occured.
So please note that editing the registry, editing desktop.ini doesn't solve the issue.
Under c:\users\loginname all user profile folders are translated and have the standard windows icon, except the pictues folder, which is not translated and does not have an icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

1. In folder `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\`, delete `Desktop.ini` (or better - first rename it).
2. Use regedit to go to
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` and delete the entry `My Pictures`.
3. Ensure that in the registry key
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` there is an entry for `My Pictures` and is pointing to
   `C:\Users\YOURNAME\Pictures`.

Take backups of everything before, and also create first a System Restore point,
just in case. Test the above points one-by-one in their order, rebooting each time,
and stop with the first one that works. Undo the ones that do not help.

Comment: This actually works (in my case). Unfortunately I did all 3 steps at once, so I cannot judge the effect of each step. The changes are not restored by windows, but apparantly no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop.ini contents for Pictures folder is below:

> [.ShellClassInfo]
>   LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21779
>   InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12688
>   IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-113
>   IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll IconIndex=-236

The LocalizedResourceName is important. To write to desktop ini, remove SYSTEM and HIDDEN attributes, update the contents, and then add back those attributes (using the Attrib.exe command)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Also this was already the content of this file.

Comment: Another thing is "Pictures" folder should have the "R" attribute set. You can check that by typing this in Command Prompt:

`attrib %userprofile%\pictures`

And to set the R attribute if it's missing, type:

`attrib +r %userprofile%\pictures`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make a difference. Also the `%userprofile%` shortcut doesn't work (win-10), one must type the full path.

Comment: That's an important hint as far as I know. Try `SET` command in Command Prompt. This lists the env. variables in the system. Fixing %userprofile% might fix the problem in your original post.

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with the `%userprofile%` shortcut, what I meant to say, is that the `attrib` command seems to not support it.

Comment: Works fine here, Gerard. Let's know if you got any error when running that command.